# SQL: How to count # of occurrances of a particular value within a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to count all of the unique occurrences of a particular string(s) from a particular column of a SQL table?

**Using this:**

```
index    gender
1        0::Male
2        0::Male
3        0::Male||1::Male
4        0::Male||1::Female
5        0::Male||1::Male||2::Female
```

**To get this:**

```
gender    count
Males     7
Females   2
```

This is what I tried, but it isn't able to account for multiple occurrences in the same cell:

```
SELECT
    SUM (CASE WHEN genders LIKE '%Male%' THEN '1' END) AS Males,
    SUM (CASE WHEN genders LIKE '%Female%' THEN '1' END) AS Females
FROM genders
```

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why storing delimited data is a poor design: it's more difficult to query.  While it's probably not what you want to hear, you could save yourself a lot of future headaches by storing the values individually, as separate rows, not as delimited lists.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server Version 18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY Key, gender VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (gender) VALUES
('0::Male'),
('0::Male'),
('0::Male||1::Male'),
('0::Male||1::Female'),
('0::Male||1::Male||2::Female');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- Method #1
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT STUFF(value, 1, pos + 1, '') AS gender
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(gender,'||','|'), '|')
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('::', value)) AS t(pos)
)
SELECT gender, COUNT(*) AS [Counter]
FROM rs
GROUP BY gender;

-- Method #2
SELECT 'Male' AS Gender
    , SUM(IIF(value LIKE '%:Male%', 1, 0)) AS [Counter]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(gender,'|')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Female' AS Gender
    , SUM(IIF(value LIKE '%:Female%', 1, 0)) AS [Counter]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(gender,'|')
ORDER BY Gender;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+---------+
| gender | Counter |
+--------+---------+
| Female |       2 |
| Male   |       7 |
+--------+---------+
```

Comment: I ended up using the CTE solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the character you are looking for is "Z"

1. If it is in a field
   the number of lines on which a character appears

```
select
count(1)
from [Table Name]
where [Field Name]
like '%Z%'
```

2. The number of Z in each value

```
select
    len([Field Name])-len(replace([Field Name],'Z','')) AS [the number of Z]
from [Table Name]
```

3. Find the number of all Zs contained in the field in the lookup table

```
select
    SUM(len([Field Name])-len(replace([Field Name],'Z',''))) AS [the number of Z]
from [Table Name]
where [Field Name]
like '%Z%'
```

Comment: Although databases have columns, not fields.